# The king and his magical diamond

Tags: story, mystery

A king seated on his throne is contemplating about the future of his kingdom as he is growing very old.

His kingdom will be safe while the magical diamond is in the kingdom.

This decently size diamond is an ordinary looking diamond, but it possesses the mighty power to protect the people of the land where it resides.

The royal guards and army have foiled many attempts made in the past by other kingdoms and by thieves to steal this diamond.

The king devises a plan to keep the diamond safe in his kingdom for many years to come, even after his death …

One day, during the day-time, the king dresses up in disguise so that no one can identify him, and he uses the secret passage that leads out of the palace; the king returns back after some time through the same way.

After few days, he does the so again.

A few days later, he announces a royal banquet in his palace garden.  Everyone in the kingdom, rich and poor, is invited.

The next day, in the middle of the night, the king disguises himself again but in a different costume; he takes the secrete passage, goes out of the palace, and returns after some time.

On the day of the royal feast, the king commands that the magical diamond be placed on a table next to his chair in the garden where the royal feast will be held (people had heard about the diamond but very few had seen it); he also posts four guards around that table for the diamond's safety.

During the feast, the people gathered are chatting, joking, eating, drinking and being entertained by the dances and musical performances.

The king gets up from his seat, leaving the diamond on its table; he takes a walk through the entire garden, stopping halfway for a chat with some of the guests.

When he returns to his chair, he tells the four guards around the diamond that “Someone just told me that a jeweller has a fool-proof plan to steal this diamond and that he will steal it before the feast ends.”
The king describes how the jeweller looks, what he is wearing and where he is seated.  The king orders the guards to detain him, take him inside, ask once what his plan is and if he denies it, immediately kill him so that he cannot execute his plan before the feast gets over.

The four guards rush towards the jeweller, take him inside; they ask him how he will steal the diamond.  The jeweller denies having made any plan to steal the diamond and the guards kill him on the spot as per their king's order and they come out of the palace to inform the king about it.  The king says “Too late:  he executed his plan successfully; the diamond was stolen,” sadly.

The horrified guards see that the table is empty, the diamond is not there.

Announcement is made that the diamond is stolen and the guards order everyone present to come to the king's table so that they can be checked.  The diamond is not found on any of the guests and the feast is concluded.

Next morning, the butler carries a breakfast to the king's bedroom, where he finds the king lying alone in his bed, his wrists slashed and a blood soaked note in his hand; the note reads “without the diamond I am nothing”.  The king is buried.

A few days pass.  The royal family receives a message from the king of a neighboring kingdom.  The message says “I stole your diamond, now I shall be invincible!”

*What was the king's plan and did the king succeed in his plan?* 
*Where is the real magical diamond? Is it with the neighboring king?*

**EDIT**

See the self answer

Comment: @can-ned_food, sure, pls go ahead

Comment: A bit nitpicky but if the diamond keeps the kingdom safe, shouldn’t the diamond protect itself from being stolen?

Comment: While this is an interesting puzzle, it appears to have multiple valid solutions. Please make sure there's enough detail in the puzzle to point to the exact solution which you're looking for. At least such that what you're looking for is a better solution than other possibilities. Without such detail, people answering have a confusing time with providing solutions which fit what's been stated, but which are not exactly what you have in mind.

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ, nice catch, this is my firsts story and the magical property of the diamond is not used anywhere in the story, so you can read it as "a diamond believed to have magical property"

Comment: @Makyen, thanks for the feedback, I will make sure that the point you mentioned is taken care of in future

Comment: Your explanation is *not part of the question* - you should make it a self-answer.  Also and obviously, as has been noted by others, there are multiple possible scenarios that fit the known facts well enough to "solve the mystery" - the details where your intended solution do not match the proffered answers are details that people might only get by guessing what you're thinking, not by interpreting provided clues (because, for those details, no clues were provided). This is basically the definition of "too broad,"  so don't be surprised if people start to vote accordingly.  Good story though!

Comment: @Rubio, thanks for the complements , did as suggested

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the entire answer, but it seems that his plan was to

> create a fake diamond and have the other country steal the fake.

On the first night:

> He sneaks out of the palace in disguise and requests the jeweller to cut a diamond similar to the real one. This would likely be done without bringing the real magic diamond or implying that the jeweller was to copy the real magic diamond. The king would have shown an image of the diamond and made up a story like "I lost my wife's ring/necklace with a diamond like this embedded in it, I need a convincing copy to fool her." Since it can be assumed that the jeweller has never seen the real magic diamond, he would have no idea what he was making a copy of.

On the second night:

> He retrieves the duplicate diamond from the jeweller. Nothing special to note here.

On the third night with the new disguise:

> Route 1: The king, in disguise, contacts a foreign party and makes the plan to steal the magic diamond at the garden party, which was just announced. The king mentions that there will be a point that the jewel is unguarded when someone else is accused of a similar plot.
>
>  Route 2: It is also possible that the king claims that he has already stolen the diamond and gives the foreign party the fake. This would be less certain, as the foreign party would know that a fake exists, as it will be displayed at the party.

During the garden party:

> The king displays the fake diamond that he had created. The king gives his orders to his guards, pointing out the jeweller that he had create the duplicate. Because the jeweller is now aware of what he created, he must be eliminated to prevent the king's plot from being exposed.
>  Route 1: At the time that the guards are killing the jeweller, the foreign party steals the fake magic diamond. This is likely done, as benzene suggested, by swallowing it.
>
>  Route 2: In case that he had passed off the fake the night before, the king swallows the real diamond and there is no plot for others to steal it.

Upon his death:

> The king, again as benzene suggested, swallows the diamond in order for it to be buried with him. With the announcement by the foreign king, no one would ever think that the magic diamond is still in the country. And with the jeweller dead, no one else would know that a fake was ever created.

Comment: cool, very nice analysis,  you are very near, also,  "during garden party" you contradicted yourself, did the foreign party swallowed the diamond or the king?

Comment: That was based off of two options of what happened during the third night. If he gave the fake away on the third night, the king swallowed the real one during the party. If he told the foreign party about the plot, then the foreign party ate the fake one at the garden party. I made an edit to clarify that those are two separate scenarios.

Comment: he cannot give the fake one on the 3rd night as the news of the theft are not spread, the other possibility is logical; though short it will take some time for me to write the explanation,

Comment: That's why I said that option was less certain, it would have required the king telling the foreign party that he had created a fake and swapped it for the real one. The foreign party would ignore the theft at the party as the theft of a fake and deliver his fake to his king. The part I'm most likely missing is why the king went around during the party. It was likely to slip the fake in someone else's food, but then the guards would have noticed it missing when the king told them about the jeweller's plot.

Comment: see the answer posted

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly how big the diamond is, but I'm guessing the king

> swallowed the diamond so it would be buried with him

Comment: nice, see the last message edited so that you can solve the entire mystery

Comment: Did the king in this case write that horrifying message himself?

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on the following facts/assumptions and narration,

> Yes, king did succeed in his plan, though at a cost of his own life through a kind of sacrifice.
>  1. His kingdom will be safe as far as the magical diamond is in the kingdom. 2. Dead persons are getting buried without an autopsy and 3. No exhume operation is practiced

Here comes the explanation for kings thoughts / actions:

> He did not trust anyone / felt none is reliable to take care of the rare diamond in his kingdom and thereby plots to
>  Get the diamond buried along with him after his death, let the suspicion go to a neighboring king and plot a conspiracy which distracts the public's attention on a jeweler (he is a king-pin, accomplice is the entire king's plot, also paid with his life) - thereby creating a message that misled all the people OF his **OWN KINGDOM**. Now comes the question of making the neighboring kings/ kingdoms also to believe that the rare diamond is **NO LONGER** with the king / within the kingdom.

For this,

> King arranges few spies whose job is to prepare and send a message after kings death that describes "I stole your diamond, now I shall be invincible!", with whom (at least in one of his secret visits) he met during his secret visits.

Also to explain his actions on the day of the feast,

> King has devised a plan B in case of his main plan getting failed (the main plan being keeping a duplicate diamond on the table with four guards protecting it, which was ordered and prepared during his one of secret visits), where the so called jeweler turned to be a traitor (either passed the message of the feast and the public display of the diamond to the neighboring enemy king so that they can use that opportunity to steal the diamond) - and the plan B being king himself swallowing the diamond, which would be buried along with him in his own kingdom

Well, there are two conspiracies can be  seen here,

> 1. Conspiracy of the jeweler, which was not clear to the king, until his secret visit and 2. conspiracy of the king, himself.

King throws the party as a bait to

> eliminate the infidel jeweler and  make his own country believe that diamond is stolen (and hence no one searches within the kingdom, where king gets buried later, as per his plan!!)

Well, this entire explanation / story assumes the fact that

> The rare diamond must be within the premises of the palace without which these answers and the narration would be jeopardized !!  ;-)